# Are there software packages that help create front-ends to SQL/RDBMS databases which can be completely customized?

Tags: database, sql

I have an idea for a website where I want to build a database of items that a user can view, filter, and sort through but not alter the data. On the backend, I would want to be able to add data, create columns, hide or show specific columns, etc.

Is there a software product out there that makes this easy? Doing it by hand wouldn't be terribly hard, but it'd be a nice bonus if someone already thought of this and has built something to do exactly what I need. :-)

OS: Any but Windows 7+ preferred
Price: Under $1000

Comment: Please add a bit more detail to your question. Which OS are you requiring this software to run on? What price are you willing to pay for software that meets these requirements?

Comment: Is this site's community planning to break all questions down by OS and price?